# Accessing Microsoft Office SharePoint 2007 over a Web service

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint-2007

I have no experience either with SharePoint, nor with Web services, but should develop a simple access to our Microsoft Office SharePoint 2007 Web server. What I have to do is to add a record to a table there, and perhaps read out some information from this or other tables. The access should be done from a JavaServlet.

Can you say where to find a tutorial about this subject or other useful information for a beginner?

Thank you for your information!
Sae1962

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search turned up the following MSDN article.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862916(v=office.12).aspx

I have used Sharepoint web services in the past however the documentation for them was abysmal.  A Microsoft MVP who I was working with at the time told me that was because they were originally designed and developed as an afterthought for Microsoft engineers and they are not recommended to use in production.  This was years ago however so perhaps this has changed now.

The better method would be to write a portlet in Sharepoint that exposes your own web service interface to perform Sharepoint related tasks utilizing the object model which is safer.